# DataGridCell get binding value

Tags: c#, binding, styles, converters, datagridcell

I try to get cell content as a class such as I bind
how can I do that?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Style.Triggers >
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15,0,0,0" />
                        </DataTrigger>
 </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

here is Converter class:

```
 public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value!= null)
            {
                //to do  value is TextBlcock and I cant get value need I
            }
            return  value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do (your question is unclear), are you looking for `value as TextBlcock`?

Comment: I bind a DataTable  it contains a Colums  to grid  like  
                dcolumn = new DataColumn("colname");
                dcolumn.Caption = "colname Caption";
                dcolumn.DataType = typeof(MyClass);
                this.Data.Columns.Add(dcolumn);
 I try to get MyClass data in converter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/7c74ec9e-e0bb-4427-9db9-d149c74571c3/wpf-datagrid-cell-color-based-on-cell-above-value?forum=wpf). The best solution seems to be

DataGridRow sending to converter

```
 <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}" Mode="OneWay">
                                    <Binding Path="." RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRow}" />
                                    <Binding Path="." RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
```